# How to get OS build number from web app?

Tags: web, operating-system

How can I get the Operating System build number (Windows, Mac etc) from within a browser?

Can use Flash or Java if have to? or something else?

Comment: What counts as a "build number" in, say, Gentoo?

Comment: There is no way to get this information.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good site that will give you all you need to know, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=VS.85).aspx

```
javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)
```

Comment: It gives you the major version numbers, Windows NT 6.1

Answer (score -1):

As a quick answer you can get all this information from the headers of a page when it is loaded over http. You can echo out the headers easily in PHP (or something similar) and they will say I AM WINDOWS - RELEASE X - BROWSER-AGENT I.E9 etc...
I think jquery can tell you what os and browser is being used easily as well.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't get reliably get the operating system build number.  Sites like [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org) will show you what values can be got (with some effort).

One exception to this is the built in phone browsers:

- [Get Android OS version from user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293394/get-android-os-version-from-user-agent)
- [Detect iOS version less than 5 with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348139/detect-ios-version-less-than-5-with-javascript)

since there is a single release build for these and you can reliably detect the version number you can assume a build number.

You can guess the build numbers for other browsers based on the OS version number, but you can't definitely prove it.

Comment: No even without a plug-in such as flash

Comment: The reason I ask is that we want our users to visit a web page and it to tell them if they have Windows XP SP3 and .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 installed etc

Comment: You can _sometimes_ detect .NET framework versions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179127/how-to-detect-net-framework-installed-in-a-web-page-pure-html-or-php

Comment: You can make guesses about the SP level too if your user is using an unmodified internet explorer - see http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html